# Given a CFG G (in Chomsky normal form) and a string w, determine whether w has more than one parse tree in G in polynomial time

Tags: complexity-theory, context-free, polynomial-time, ambiguity

So I have the following language:

C = {<G,w>|G is a CFG in Chomsky normal form and w has more than one parse tree in G}

How to prove that this language is in P (decidable in deterministic polynomial time)?

I tried to come up with a polynomial-time algorithm and tried to show a reduction to a different language in P, but couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify the CYK parsing algorithm so that it *counts* the number of parse trees for each word.

Given a word $w = w_1 \ldots w_n$, for each $1 \leq i \leq j \leq n$ and non-terminal $A$, we will count the number of parse trees rooted at $A$ and generating $w_i \ldots w_j$. If $i = j$ then this number is either zero or one, depending on whether $A \to w_i$ is a rule. Otherwise, all parse trees are of the form $$A \to BC \to^* (w_i \ldots w_k) (w_{k+1} \ldots w_j)$$
and so if we know, for each $i \leq k < j$ and for each $B,C$ such that a rule $A \to BC$ exists, how many parse trees there are for $w_i \ldots w_k$ rooted at $B$ and for $w_{k+1} \ldots w_j$ rooted at $C$, then we can count the number of parse trees of $w_i \ldots w_j$ rooted at $A$.

You are interested in whether the number of parse trees of $w_1 \ldots w_n$ rooted at $S$ is larger than one or not. Therefore you can cap the numbers at two, thus avoiding large numbers and so reducing the running time.

Comment: Thanks! I tried a similar approach with CYK but the dots just didn't connect for me.
I found another idea which I'm not sure about:
Since the grammar is in CNF, the parsing of a word of length k is 2k-1 steps. Let's say the grammar has n production rules. So at each step, we have at most n rules to choose from. Thus, we can create ALL derivations at length 2k-1 at n^(2k-1) steps. Then we can check if at least 2 of those derivations create the string w. Since all production rules are part of the input, the time is polynomial at the length of the input. thoughts about this proof?